# macports Found broken file(s)

Tags: macports

Every time I install a new package, I see this error message:

```
--->  Found 1 broken file(s), matching files to ports
Warning: No port py24-scipy found in the index; can't rebuild
--->  Broken files found, but all associated ports are not in the index and so cannot be rebuilt.
```

It got into this state after I did a "port upgrade outdated".

I'm pretty sure I'm not using py24-scipy (I use py27), so I'd simply like to find the file which is triggering the warning and remove it.

I tried running "port install XXX -d", to see if it would show me where the broken file is, but it didn't.

Comment: I would try 'port installed py24-scipy' to see if it is installed and do 'port uninstall py24-scipy' if it is. Like you say, it's probably no longer in use.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comment from @Vortexfive (thanks), this solved the problem:

```
SCML-JRichardson:pdf2html5 jric$ port installed py24-scipy
The following ports are currently installed:
  py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45 (active)
```

That's weird:

```
SCML-JRichardson:pdf2html5 jric$ port installed all | grep scipy
py-scipy @0.11.0_0
py-scipy @0.13.2_0 (active)
py27-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45
py27-scipy @0.13.2_0+gcc45 (active)
```

But anyway,

```
Password:
--->  Unable to uninstall py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45, the following ports depend on it:
--->    py-scipy @0.11.0_0
Error: org.macports.uninstall for port py24-scipy returned: Please uninstall the ports that depend on py24-scipy first.
Please see the log file for port py24-scipy for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_registry_portfiles_py24- scipy_0.11.0_0+gcc45/py24-scipy/main.log
Warning: Failed to execute portfile from registry for py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45
--->  Unable to uninstall py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45, the following ports depend on it:
--->    py-scipy @0.11.0_0
Error: port uninstall failed: Please uninstall the ports that depend on py24-scipy first.
```

Try Deactivate py-scipy so it does not block py24-scip removal

```
SCML-JRichardson:pdf2html5 jric$ sudo port deactivate py-scipy
--->  Deactivating py-scipy @0.13.2_0
--->  Cleaning py-scipy
```

uninstall py24-scipy - bt does not work as py-scipy is still there

```
SCML-JRichardson:pdf2html5 jric$ sudo port uninstall py24-scipy
--->  Unable to uninstall py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45, the following ports depend on it:
--->    py-scipy @0.11.0_0
Error: org.macports.uninstall for port py24-scipy returned: Please uninstall the ports that depend on py24-scipy first.
Please see the log file for port py24-scipy for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_registry_portfiles_py24-scipy_0.11.0_0+gcc45/py24-scipy/main.log
Warning: Failed to execute portfile from registry for py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45
--->  Unable to uninstall py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45, the following ports depend on it:
--->    py-scipy @0.11.0_0
Error: port uninstall failed: Please uninstall the ports that depend on py24-scipy first.
```

Now try removing both py24-scipy py-scipy@0.11.0_0

```
SCML-JRichardson:pdf2html5 jric$ sudo port uninstall py24-scipy py-scipy@0.11.0_0
--->  Uninstalling py-scipy @0.11.0_0
--->  Cleaning py-scipy
--->  Deactivating py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45
--->  Cleaning py24-scipy
--->  Uninstalling py24-scipy @0.11.0_0+gcc45
--->  Cleaning py24-scipy
SCML-JRichardson:pdf2html5 jric$ sudo port activate py-scipy
--->  Computing dependencies for py-scipy
--->  Activating py-scipy @0.13.2_0
--->  Cleaning py-scipy
```

Comment: Note you probably installed py-scipy by mistake at some stage instead of using the versioned version. I think the error is caused by removal of the obsolete py24-scipy from macports